# Notifying LiveData observers but without passing them any data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a case where I have LiveData observer that monitors a condition that indicates if the user is signed in. The observer will only get notified when the user is signed in. I don't need to pass any data to the observer. When the observer gets called, it simply means that the user is signed in:

```
val observer = Observer<String> { signedIn ->
  // The user is signed in. Do something...
}

model.isSignedIn.observe(this, observer)
```

In my viewmodel I believe I'm suppose to update the observer as follows:

```
isSignedIn.setValue()
```

Is this the proper way to update an observer that doesn't require any data sent to it? LiveData is really about notifying observers about data changes. But in my example, I'm using it to notify about an event change. It's a subtle difference and maybe using LiveData for this case is not the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

In that case you can use `LiveData`, it has no restrictions, especially if you want to be lifecycle aware.
If you want to have more clear API for that case you can use extension function mechanism. And in your case, suggest to use Unit type for live data variable.

```
typealias NoValueLiveData = MutableLiveData<Unit>

fun NoValueLiveData.setValue() {
    this.value = Unit
}
```